# Trigger automatic pull/push for submodule after new commit appear

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-submodules, git-config

I have a project `A` and I have added a submodule to another project `B`.

I see that the submodule used in `A` is referring to a particular commit, and I would like this to be updated every time a new commit appears in `B`.

Is it possible to trigger an automatic pull/push of the submodule in `A` when `B` is updated?
Or this procedure has to be done always by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider:

- making sure your submodule B, in repository A, [follows a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309) (`main`, for instance)
- using a [multi-project pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html)

> You can set up [GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/index.html) across multiple projects, so that a pipeline in one project can trigger a pipeline in another project. You can visualize the entire pipeline in one place, including all cross-project inter-dependencies.

Your first pipeline would be triggered [only on pushes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefs--exceptrefs).
And it includes a trigger to your project A, which would then execute a [git submodule update --remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt---remote), in order to update the submodule `B`.